# Output of a simple for loop?

Tags: c

I'm VERY new to c programming. The output of the following program is 
One Two Two One but I don't know why. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  {
  int i, j, k = 100;
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
     printf("One");
     for(j=0;k;j++)
        {
           printf("Two");
           k -=50;
        }
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: use a debugger to see that the inner loop is executed twice

Comment: Yes, now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger.  You will benefit more than by asking a question on Stack Overflow.  Hint: Zero evaluates to false, which is why the inner loop executes twice for `i=0`.

Comment: First, You need `main` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Outer loop:

The outer for loop executes twice. Because i starts at 0, the condition `i<0` is satisfied, so it runs. After it runs i gets incremented to 1, runs again, i gets incremented to 2, then doesn't run because the condition `i<2` is no longer satisfied. That is where your two outputs of "one" come from.

#### Inner loop:

Every time the outer loop runs it creates the inner for loop. j starts at 0 but the condition for the inner loop is just `k`. At first, `k` is set to 100. Here's where it gets messy. In order for a for loop to run, the condition must be "not false". False can be either a numerical value of `0` or just `null`. Since it's not either one of those the inner for loop runs, and unless the condition is manually changed by something outside the for loop, it will run forever. Luckily it is in fact being changed inside the for loop and after running twice (and outputting `two` twice), the value of k is now 0 and exits the loop.

#### Put 'em together:

To summarize, the order of execution is:

1. outer loop (`i=0`, `"one"` gets printed)
2. inner loop (j=0, k=100, `"two"` gets printed)
3. inner loop (j=1, k=50, `"two"` gets printed)

   - k=0, inner loop completes (notice the j didn't get used here)
4. outer loop (i=1, `"one"` gets printed)

   - k=0, inner loop does not execute even once
   - i=2, outer loop completes

Comment: I put it inside main and it ran just fine.